# How do I see on Jenkins if my build it's in qa?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to see on jenkins if my build number is in qa environment. How do I see this ? If anyone has an example video or something.. will be great.

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on how you have your Jenkins setup, how your workflow works at your organisation and how you choose to show it.

You could do things like tag builds with tags like "Passed QA" if that is what you want, or, you could be using a proper pipeline approach in which case you could see if your build had made it to that part of the pipeline by looking at the pipeline view.

Alternatively, you may have different builds for different stages (or at least tasks in Jenkins to move your build to different environments, like QA and production) - if you look if your build has downstream builds then follow that to see if it gets to on that says in QA that would tell you if you do it that way.

Comment: So where exactly it's the pipeline view? I have my build number. We have separate pipeline for qa